# C# - Get closest greater number in a list

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an unsorted list of subtitle lines which looks like this:

```
public class SubtitleItem{
        public int StartTime { get; set; } //In milliseconds
        public int EndTime { get; set; } //This too
        ...
}
```

Let's say the video's current position is at 1000ms and there are three subtitle lines which starts at 900ms, 1200ms, and 1300ms. I want the second line. Since I cannot perfectly sync the video position, I need to get the closest subtitle line which starts after the current video position.

Note: I sync every 100ms.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Adding code or showing what you tried might help you get an answer :)

Comment: Wow, so many LINQ-ers here. And all they sort in order to get the minimum, which everyone knows is not the best algorithm for that. While simple `for` / `foreach` loop will do the same in linear (O(N)) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Linq.

Assuming your subtitles are in something which implements IEnumerable and the current time is in a var named currentTime you can do:

```
var subtitle = (from subtitle in subtitles
                let diff = subtitle.StartTime - currentTime
                where diff > 0
                order by diff).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var nextSubtitle = subtitles.OrderBy(i=> i.StartTime)
                       .Where(i=> i.StartTime > currentTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public SubtitleItem GetNextSubtitle(int currentPosition, List<SubtitleItem> items)
{
    return items.OrderBy(i => i.StartTime).First(i => i.StartTime > currentPosition);
}
```